# Insert Pseudo-Code as Figure

Tags: table-of-contents, miktex, texmaker, article, pseudocode

this is my first post on tex.stackexchange, so please forgive any violations on proper question-asking.

I'm currently writting a thesis about a project that contains a lot of coding. I would like to add the most important (and "genius") parts of the code as pseudo-code into the thesis and would like to have them listed in my regular `\listoffigures`, ideally with a hint that those are pseudo-code pieces.

What I intend is something similar to this:

**List Of Figures**

1. someNormalFigure
2. anotherNormalFigure
3. beautifulAlgorithm (PseudoCode)

The name of the pseudo-code piece should be "beautifulAlgorithm" and not "beautifulAlgorithm (PseudoCode)".

I'm using TexMaker, MikTex and the `article` environment. (just in case this in necessary or useful information to anyone)

Comment: Enclose the desired algorithms inside a `figure` environment and use the standard `\caption`.

Comment: Welcome to our site! You could load the package `caption` and put `\captionof{figure}[beautifulAlgorithm]{beautifulAlgorithm (PseudoCode}` below your snippet.

Comment: How high is the chance, that the pseudo code will be longr than one page?

Comment: @Johannes_B : It is highly probable that this will happen at least once.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi : So using `\captionof{figure}...` changes only the output inside the `listoffigures`, not the "internal representation" ?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my comment above. I misunderstood you, I think. Please take a look at my answer if this is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pseudo code is taken from somewhere else on this side. As you have not given an MWE, I had to guess something. The package `caption` helps you by imitating captions from other environments. The default behaviour (layout) of the pseudo code is not changed (at least not in my example).

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}[h] % [h] just to get it behind the list of figures.
    \centering
    \rule{3cm}{2cm}
    \caption{1. Figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{algorithm}
    \captionof{figure}[beautifulAlgorithm (PseudoCode)]{beautifulAlgorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \Procedure{MyProcedure}{}
            \State $\textit{stringlen} \gets \text{length of }\textit{string}$
            \State $i \gets \textit{patlen}$
            \If {$i > \textit{stringlen}$} \Return false
            \EndIf
            \State $j \gets \textit{patlen}$
            \If {$\textit{string}(i) = \textit{path}(j)$}
            \State $j \gets j-1$.
            \State $i \gets i-1$.
            \State \textbf{goto} \emph{loop}.
            \State \textbf{close};
            \EndIf
            \State $i \gets i+\max(\textit{delta}_1(\textit{string}(i)),\textit{delta}_2(j))$.
            \State \textbf{goto} \emph{top}.
            \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{3cm}{2cm}
    \caption{2. Figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I intended, thank you very much. I'll use another pseudo-code style though.

Comment: @krouch Glad to hear that. For next questions, please try to provide a bit more information (compilable code) which makes it so much easier to help. But for now: have fun TeXing!